# some js files are not read by google devTool (local server)

Tags: javascript, html

I create a local server with python.
everything looks ok from this screen: [local server home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrotb.png)

but when I open my html file and devTools, 'input.js' doesn't appear in the sources, so I don't have the functionality of that file :
[devTools sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4OFB.png)

I create a local server exactly for this reason, but I haven't solved the problem.

[this is how i created the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfMbB.png)

Comment: Please provide some code of how you built your server and included files.

Comment: hello, I just add a photo to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The devTools will only list the files that you referenced - for example in your HTML. If you reference all files, they will come up on your browser.

The listing of the files on the `local server home` is done by the server, not the client!

Imagine your server would share arbitrary file system information with the world. That would be a huge security hole.

What you of course can do is return information about the file system as JSON (not HTML, as you currently see it on the local server home) and then `fetch` each file in your scripts.

Comment: hi, in my html file i linked script righit that:  `<script src="game.js" type="module"></script>` .
I have 3 js file :game.js, snake.js, input.js.

the functions of the latter are not present, and actually when I open the devTool to check the presence of the file, it is not there, but it does not give me any error.

Comment: Because snake and input are not linked from anywhere. you are not linking them in the html or in game.js.

Comment: but snake.js appears, input.js not.

Comment: then input.js is not linked.